# setData on RemoteViewService intents

Tags: android, widget, broadcastreceiver, android-widget, commonsware

What is the use of

```
serviceIntent.setData(Uri.parse(serviceIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
```

on the following `Intent` in an AppWidgetProvider class (see code below)

According to the CommonsWare book, the reason is:

> While your application has access to your RemoteViewsService Class object, the app widget host will not, and so we need something that will work across process boundaries. You could elect to add your own  to the RemoteViewsService and use an Intent based on that, but that would make your service more publicly visible than you might want.

Source: The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development
https://commonsware.com/Android/

But when I delete this line, nothing changes. The widget still works.

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {

        [...]

        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, WidgetService.class);
        serviceIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
        serviceIntent.setData(Uri.parse(serviceIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));

        views.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.stack_view, serviceIntent);
        views.setEmptyView(R.id.stack_view, R.id.empty_view);

        [...]

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }
```

Comment: Back in the day, we were told to use that for our adapter-driven app widgets. It never made that much sense to me, and I haven't really researched the point much in the past few years. I'll take a look at this sometime, but I fear it may be a while before I get to it...

Comment: Ok, maybe I can find something out in the meantime. Also in your book you say that Google recommends to pass the `ApplicationContext` when creating the `RemoteViewsFactory` in the `onGetViewFactory` method of the `RemoteViewsService`, but it was unclear why that is. Has there be any clarification in the meantime or is it still unclear?

Comment: Usually that is to avoid memory leaks, though I am unclear what specific leak scenario worried them. I deal very little with app widgets, and so I need to do more research to see if there has been updated advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.
If you don't use `setData`, the system can not distinguish between different service intents, which causes it to call `onGetViewFactory` only once for multiple widgets and send the same intent to all of them.
If you for example send the app widget id to your `RemoteViewsService` and from their to your `RemoteViewsFactory` and display it in every item, it will display the same id for all instances of the widget, if you don't use `setData`.